# How to, drop down menu that returns values from another workbook.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create a dropdown menu that populates certain cells from another worksheet. 
My reference sheet is like this. 
 [Reference sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydsPB.png)

Now I would like to select a currency pair from a dropdown (see below picture) and have the inputted price levels return in this table automatically.

[Sheet I'd like the values copied into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGMHx.png)

I have no clue on how to begin this, I was thinking of a vlookup function or maybe an array? Not sure how to go about it though. I need an example shown then I can fill in the rest. Thanks in advance for your help.  Cheers.

Comment: I meant to say worksheet not another workbook.

Comment: Which part are you having troubles with? Referencing another sheet, creating the dropdown menu, or setting cell values based on the dropdown menu's value?

Comment: Setting cell values based on dropdown menu's value.

Comment: They are posted in the links.

Comment: np, thanks for taking a look at my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the Prices data is located at `Sht(13)` range `B1:AD8` and that the currency combination is at `C2` try these formulas:

Proximal Zone Price: `=VLOOKUP($C$2,'Sht(13)'!$B$1:$AD$8,27,0)`

Distal Zone Price: `=VLOOKUP($C$2,'Sht(13)'!$B$1:$AD$8,29,0)`

[image]

I'm afraid the columns (27 & 29) have to be hard code as in data does not seem to have a unique identifier for WK Supply Distal and WK Supply Proximal. Also a working column can be used to hold the column number.

*Can also use these Index\Match combination formulas*

Assuming Proximal and Distal Prices are located at column `AB` and `AD` respectively.

Proximal Zone Price:

`=INDEX('Sht(13)'!$AD$1:$AD$8,MATCH($C$2,'Sht(13)'!$B$1:$B$8,0))`

Distal Zone Price:

`=INDEX('Sht(13)'!$AD$1:$AD$8,MATCH($C$2,'Sht(13)'!$B$1:$B$8,0))`

Comment: Briliant!! It appears to be working. It requires some manual manipulation but it works. 

Quick question, can I have the table array include currency pairs, and just the proximal column or do I need to include coumns B to AD for it to work? That would eliminate the large column index numbering.

Comment: Absolutely, just updated the answer with the Index\Match formula

Comment: Just note that I found easier to deal with the large column number and have a standard range that to use a difference range for each formula...

Comment: EEM your vlookup is briliant. I set my array to include the entire reference sheet, changed the reference colum for each proximal and distal zone. Your solution worked like a charm. I have saved your response for future reference if required. Brilliant mate, thank you.